# If a Grain subscribes to an Orleans Stream, will it never get deactivated?

Tags: orleans

If a Grain subscribes to an Orleans Stream, does that mean that this Grain will never get deactivated? Or will it get deactivated, and just become active again when a message gets published to the Stream that it was subscribed to?

Comment: please add to your question to make it more specific by stating whether you're using an explicit stream subscription or an implicit stream subscription

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both cases, implicit and explicit, grain will be deactivated if no new events arrive, and will be reactivated when a new event comes.